# Cppyy pythonization with templates?

Tags: python, c++, templates, binding, cppyy

Is there a way to write pythonizations in cppyy that work for all templates?

I have a class in C++ that requires a template

```
template <typename TValueType>
Bound<TValueType> Bound<TValueType>::buildInclusiveBound(TValueType value) {
  return Bound<TValueType>{BoundCategory::Inclusive, value};
}
```

I noticed that when I was writing a pythonization of this function, this did not work

```
import cppyy.gbl as Cpp

Cpp.Bound.__str__ = lambda self: "test"
```

but

```
import cppyy.gbl as Cpp

Cpp.Bound['double'].__str__ = lambda self: "test"
```

did.

Comment: @WimLavrijsen do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bound` isn't a class just as much as e.g. `std::vector` isn't, so there's no Python proxy to Pythonize. Easiest solution is probably a name check using a pre-registered pythonizor. Example:

```
import cppyy

cppyy.cppdef(r"""\
namespace MyNamespace {
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(T t) : m_data(t) {}
    T m_data;
};
}""")

def pythonize_myclass(klass, name):
    if 'MyClass' in name:
        klass.__str__ = lambda x: str(x.m_data)

cppyy.py.add_pythonization(pythonize_myclass, 'MyNamespace')

mi = cppyy.gbl.MyNamespace.MyClass[int](42)
print(mi)

md = cppyy.gbl.MyNamespace.MyClass['double'](42.)
print(md)
```